# What's wrong with my python solution to Project Euler #12?

Tags: python, algorithm, math

**Possible Spoiler Warning**

I've spent ages trying to improve this algorithm and work out what's going wrong, but I can't seem to work out why the outputted answer is incorrect.

I'm trying to solve [Project Euler #12](http://projecteuler.net/problem=12), to get the lowest triangular number to have over 500 divisors, but it says my answer is incorrect.

Here is my Python code:

```
import time

# function to get the number of divisors
def div(n):
    d=2
    for i in range(2,int(n**.5)+2):
        if (n % i) == 0:
            d += 1
    return d

start = time.time()

w = True
n=m=1
while w:
    n += 1
    s = (n*(n+1))/2 # nth triangle number
    r = div(s)
    if r > m:
        m = r
        print s,"has",r,"divisors"
        if r > 500:
            w = False

print "Solved in",((time.time()-start)*1000),"milliseconds"
```

And the output for that code is this (in 66 seconds):

```
3 has 2 divisors
6 has 4 divisors
36 has 6 divisors
120 has 9 divisors
```

...

```
76576500 has 289 divisors
103672800 has 325 divisors
236215980 has 385 divisors
842161320 has 513 divisors
Solved in 65505.5799484 milliseconds
```

However, if I input 842161320 into the Project Euler problem, it says it's incorrect.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your initial output does not match the sample output in the problem statement - 28 should be the first triangle number with six divisors.

Comment: @Odomontois - I know, but just look if you [search project euler](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=project+euler) there are 4554 results at the moment so I'm not exactly alone. Also I did all of them up to now without even using any other websites but just got really stuck on this one

Comment: You might want to check this “[eulerlib](http://pastebin.com/MP78s8vQ)” I've created for some tools.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see two bugs:

- Your `div` function is broken: `div(24) == 5`, while it should be 8
- Your 1st triangular number would be `3`, although it should be `1`

You could implement a working `div` like this:

```
import math
def divisors(n):
  return sum(1 for x in range(1, n+1) if n % x == 0)
```

Also, that code is inefficient as hell, some suggestions to improve it are:

Instead of calculating the `n`th triangular number using your formula, use a rolling sum:

```
import itertools

s = 0
for i in itertools.count(1):
  s += i
  if div(s) > 500:
    print s
    break
```

Also, Use [prime factors to calculate the number of divisors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor#Further_notions_and_facts). You can create a prime factor cache for maximum performance.

Comment: Right - the reason that that 1 wasn't appearing is that I set `n=1`, so it starts a little bit ahead. I was originally using a rolling sum but changed it to the nth formula. The only remaining problem is that div function

Comment: @Alex: The wikipedia article I linked tells you that the number of divisors can be calculated using the prime factor representation of the number. Given that you have the prime factors `p1**x1 * p2**x2 * p3**x3`, then the number of divisors is `(x1+1)(x2+1)(x3+1)`. You can also use the brute-force approach and simply check for every number from 1 to `sqrt(n)` if it's a divisor (see my answer for a suggestion).

Comment: Niklas - have now used brute-force and simply doubled the value of 1 to `sqrt(n)` and it works just fine (apart from 1 where it returns 2!) but it now does the whole thing in only 6 seconds - see my answer

Comment: @Alex: Glad I could help :) If my answer was helpful, you are invited to upvote and accept. By the way, your `div` function returns wrong results for all numbers with an odd divisor count (AKA as square numbers 1, 4, 9, 16...)

Answer (score 2):

You are undercounting the total number of divisors. 36, for example, has 9 divisors: 1,2,3,4,6,9,12,18,36. It's true the algorithm only needs to test numbers smaller than `sqrt(n)` to find all divisors, but you still need to include the implied "large" divisors in your count.

Answer (score 0):

### Solved

With the help of Niklas, and changing my `div` method, I've got the answer. Also, it's now only takes 8% of the time my previous algorithm took.

The algorithm now looks like this:

```
import time
import itertools

def div(n):
    d=0
    for i in range(1,int(n**.5)+1):
        if (n % i) == 0:
            d += 1
    return 2*d

start = time.time()

s = m = 0
for i in itertools.count(1):
    s += i
    r = div(s)
    if r > m:
        m = r
        print s,"has",r,"factors"
        if div(s) > 500:
            break

print "Solved in",((time.time()-start)*1000),"milliseconds"
```

Comment: your `div()` function is incorrect (try `div(4)` or `div(9)`)

Comment: yes, if `n` is square of some number, this number counts twice in `div()`

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft it works in this instance - I know that it isn't fully correct but it solves the puzzle